# Adding string to url on htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that redirects from www.page.com/timmy to www.page.com/

I would like to redirect www.page.com/timmy to www.page.com/#timmy

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to redirect `www.page.com/timmy` to `www.page.com/#timmy`

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^timmy  /#timmy   [L,NC,NE]
```

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC,NE] with [R=301,L,NC,NE]